# ADB connect to a device via TCP/IP

Tags: adb, connection-issues

I'm trying to use `adb connect`:

```
 connect <host>[:<port>]       - connect to a device via TCP/IP
                                 Port 5555 is used by default if no port number is specified.
```

and this is what I get:

```
mbp:~ alexus$ adb connect 10.0.0.18
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
unable to connect to 10.0.0.18:5555
mbp:~ alexus$
```

`USB debugging` is on and 10.0.0.18 is IP of my Android device, I'm able to do it via USB cable w/out any issues... any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following these instructions:

1) Open the command prompt and navigate to your sdk/platform-tools/ folder.

2) Type `adb tcpip 5555` with your device plugged in

3) Type `adb connect <your device ip address>:5555`

4) At this point you unplug your device and type `adb logcat`

5) At times, such as unplugging/plugging into a USB device, the `logcat` will become disconnected, just redo steps 3 & 4.

From my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/using-usb-peripherals-with-hardware-debug/46343#46343).

Comment: For me adb tcpip 555 command is giving the following error

Comment: error: no devices/emulators found