# Is there any trick to set ADBD to work on TCP/IP on a non-rooted device?

Tags: adb, remote-control, remote-access

What I want is to control a device from remote:

- turn display on/off,
- launch a specified application (clock),
- open a website.

On a rooted device, I've installed a SSHD app, then I logged in to the device:

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

Then I can launch `adb` on my computer, connect to the device and perform various `adb` commands.

*Can I do this on a non-rooted device?* I've found that `setprop` requires root access.

Or, *is there any app*, which have TCP/WWW interface to do such things? (I've installed an IP camera app, which have URL interface for turning the camera LED on/off, beside usual camera functions, e.g. make snapshot.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB connect to a device via TCP/IP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49681/adb-connect-to-a-device-via-tcp-ip)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command, it restarts `adbd` on the android device after setting the tcp/ip port to the value you want (5555/tcp is a default) :

```
$ adb tcpip 5555
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `adb shell` command. It gives you super user permissions in the connected device.

Comment: But I can't `adb` until I have not set to tcp mode.

Comment: If I set `adb` to TCP/IP mode, will it revert to USB mode at next boot?

Comment: Please add some detail or steps to make this a complete answer.