# disconnect adb of device connected over TCP does not work

Tags: adb

I run the following command to connect device over TCP ;

```
adb connect 192.168.56.102:5555
```

I am not able now to disconnect it  I even made two attempts :

```
 adb disconnect 192.168.56.102:5555
```

The second is , I reboot adb

```
  adb reboot
```

Unfortunately, when I run `adb devices`  , the connection is still there :

```
List of devices attached
192.168.56.102:5555 device
```

Brief, I am looking for the [opposite of this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49682/42566)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just use "adb disconnect" and it worked fine for me. See the photo below:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

To kill the server currently running you need to type: `adb kill-server` in command prompt. This should stop the instance of a running server.

Answer (score 2):

Use `adb -s deviceName disconnect`.

Comment: `deviceSerial` I would say.