# What is the way to debug multiple android device ie more than number of ports in PC in parallel?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, lan

I need to connect 10 device via usb at once. Does adb detect multiple android devices connected via usb hub?
I have explored connecting via tcpip one by one using the existing ports, but the problem is if the LAN is not very stable , it gets disconnected and I have to connect all over again. If I could connect all my devices via usb hub I wont have that issue.

I have gone through this issue: [Using USB peripherals with hardware debug](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/using-usb-peripherals-with-hardware-debug)

Comment: ADB should detect multiple devices (check using `adb devices`) on USB, have you tried it? However, it depends on the USB hub and ports whether they provide enough power for multiple devices to be detected.

Comment: afaik all devices must set to same port (5037 or 5555) and connected via `-s` <serialno>

Comment: A [related post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924274) says that by default adb can handle up to 15 devices. If you need more you have to start separate instances of adb.

Comment: @AndrewT. That's what the question is for, if you can check `adb devices` and update the answer, I can place an order for a USB hub on amazon.

Comment: @Robert Yes I have gone through that answer, but doesn't answer whether the devices connected via hub are automatically detected or do we need some sort of driver to get it going.

Comment: @Boladin The USB standard defines that USB hubs are transparent for the the PC and the devices. Therefore it does not make any difference if you connect a device directly or with 6 USB hubs in between.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for confirming, even my understanding was hinting so. Before placing an order for a USB hub, I just wanted to confirm from someone who have tried debugging multiple devices in parallel connecting via USB hub.

Comment: @Boladin FWIW, I've debugged more than 1 Android devices connected to a hub on Macbook. All of them were detected, but [Mac disabled them soon afterward because they used too much power](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204377). That's why I mentioned the "provide enough power" remark on my previous comment.